# Создание огромного количества однотипных элементов в WinForms C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Добрый всем вечер. Озадачен таким вопросом: у меня есть список из 500+ Panel, все они лежат в другой panel от фреймворка metro (они со скролом там и т.д.). Дело в том, что пока элементов Panel ~100 ничего не виснет, однако при больших количествах начинаются проблемы, заметны прогрузки и т.д. Каким образом возможно оптимизировать сей процесс, чтобы и функциональность не потерялась и не так подвисало.

Конкретная задача: сделать такой же список из песен как в вк, т.е. я под каждый трек выделяю panel, в которой кнопочка play и название. Может есть какие-то идеи по оптимизации, ведь треков может быть и 3000+, тогда совсем беда.

Мне надо чтобы список выглядел так:

[image]

Comment: Виртуализируйте.

Comment: Можно подробнее пожалуйста?

Comment: Подробнее здесь: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/optimizing-performance-controls#Displaying. Я надеюсь, вы не создаёте ваши элементы вручную, а используете Binding и ListView с привязкой ItemsSource?

Comment: Если честно создавал эти Panel через цикл, т.к. не компетентен в данном вопросе. Посмотрел ListView и не совсем понял как мне добиться такого же визуального эффекта. Это ведь таблица. А мне надо чтобы список выглядел так:
http://imgur.com/a/458uw
Можете подсказать как это можно реализовать?

Comment: @Max Перешли бы на `WPF`, ох натворили бы там дизайн себе с легкостью и без всяких заморочек.

Comment: Походу так и сделаю, все с этим WinForms не так...

Answer (score 3):

Скрывай те панели, которые не попадают в видимую область.
Просто ставь Отображаемые в нужное положение.

Comment: А если мне например надо будет быстренько проскролить в конец списка, пока я там буду все .Hide()ить пользователь уснет

Comment: Так хайдить и показывать надо будет только то, что на экране.

Answer (score 2):

А если скролить не Panel', а список песен? Объясняю идею. У вас есть список песен в памяти и 100 объектов Panel к примеру. При скроллинге вы отслеживаете смещение в списке песен и заменяете label'ы d Panel'ях. А чтобы пользователь примерно понимал сколько песен в списке поставьте для ScrolBar соответствующую длину.

Comment: Я понял вашу идею, но тогда не будет плавности, т.к. тексты будут заменяться, но нет самого эффекта скролла как-бы

Comment: Я нем могу утверждать со 100%-й вероятностью, поскольку так не делал сам, но мне представляется, что эффект скролла можно эмулировать. Представьте, что у вас колесо из ста Panel'ей, которое крутится по кругу, но при прохождении каждого элемента через определенную точку значение лэйбла этого элеиента меняется. Где-то за кулисами, так что пользователь этого не видит,  и когда он докручивает до нужного Panel, то он имеет ожидаемое значение. Подразумевается, что Panels больше, чем влазит на один экран

Comment: Хотя это, конечно, только идея:)